# Rank with current order

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table like this:

```
col1     | col2   
__________________
15077244 | 544648 
15077320 | 544648
15080285 | 544632
15382858 | 544648
15584221 | 544648
15584222 | 544648
15584223 | 544628
15584224 | 544628
15584225 | 544628
15584226 | 544628
15584227 | 544632
15584228 | 544632
```

And I want to rank it as the col2 value changed as in example below (This one is that I want to achieve):

```
col1     | col2   | rank 
________________________
15077244 | 544648 | 1
15077320 | 544648 | 1
15080285 | 544632 | 2
15382858 | 544648 | 1
15584221 | 544648 | 1
15584222 | 544648 | 1
15584223 | 544628 | 3
15584224 | 544628 | 3
15584225 | 544628 | 3
15584226 | 544628 | 3
15584227 | 544632 | 2
15584228 | 544632 | 2
```

I found an answer that suggest me to use DENSE_RANK() function. So I use it:

```
SELECT col1, col2, DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY col2) as rank     
FROM myTable
```

but when I use it it change the order of col1, like this:

```
col1      | col2   |   rank
____________________________
15584223  | 544628 |    1
15584224  | 544628 |    1
15584225  | 544628 |    1
15584226  | 544628 |    1
15080285  | 544632 |    2
15584227  | 544632 |    2
15584228  | 544632 |    2
15077244  | 544648 |    3
15077320  | 544648 |    3
15382858  | 544648 |    3
15584221  | 544648 |    3
15584222  | 544648 |    3
```

Now when I use ORDER BY at the end of my SELECT query like ORDER BY col1, I have data with correct order but RANKS are wrong, becouse for example col2 value 544648 has RANK 3 but it should have RANK 1.

How to use DENSE_RANK function or something different that helps me RANK my col2 values without changing an data order?

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your order for `dense_rank` to `desc`. And order the results by `col1` `asc`.

**[Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0ce2c/1/0)**

```
SELECT 
    col1
  , col2
  , DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY col2 DESC) as rank     
FROM myTable
ORDER BY col1 ASC
```

Comment: I thought this too at first.  And it works well with the sample data.  But if you change the fist value to anything smaller than the next value, then I don't believe this will return the correct results.  I think the OP wants the ordering based on the smallest col1 value.

Answer (score 0):

While there may be an easier solution, here's one approach using a subquery with `row_number` to establish a grouping of results, ordering by `min(col1)`:

```
SELECT t.col1, t.col2, t2.rank     
FROM myTable t JOIN (
  SELECT MIN(col1) minCol1, col2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MIN(col1)) rank
  FROM myTable
  GROUP BY col2
  ) t2 ON t.col2 = t2.col2
ORDER BY t.col1
```

- [Sample Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dQSrQvG7QLhiTqoqWDJq21/0)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquery that with a windowed minimum.

```
;WITH CorrelatedDistinctCount AS
(
    SELECT
        D.col1,
        D.col2,
        (
            SELECT 
                COUNT(DISTINCT(X.col2))
            FROM
                Data X
            WHERE
                X.col1 <= D.col1) AS DistinctCol2Count
    FROM
        Data D
)
SELECT
    C.col1,
    C.col2,
    MIN(C.DistinctCol2Count) OVER (PARTITION BY C.col2) AS rank
FROM
    CorrelatedDistinctCount C
ORDER BY
    C.col1 ASC
```